# Apache ProxyPass + RewriteRule?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, proxypass

I've set up an apache config to try to redirect `/login` and to ProxyPass all other requests:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/login$"
RewriteRule "^/login$" "https://sub.example.org/$1" [L,R]

SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPassMatch   ^/login ! # Prevent proxy on /login
ProxyPassReverse ^/login ! # Prevent proxy on /login
ProxyPassMatch   ^/      https://sub.example.org/
ProxyPassReverse ^/      https://sub.example.org/
ProxyPreserveHost off
RequestHeader set Host sub.example.org
Header set Host alt.example.org
```

Most results that I've checked are as I expect:

- alt.example.org/login redirects to sub.example.org/login
- alt.example.org/users shows the content for sub.example.org/users (without redirect)

...but https://alt.example.org/ (empty path) results in a `Location` header with the value `https://alt.example.org^/login`.  **Wow! What's causing that redirect with the `^` in the domain, and why does it reference `alt` instead of `sub`?**

The log from the Rails application which is running above apache says that the Rails app itself is actually redirecting to https://sub.example.org/login, which makes better sense because the ProxyPass means that Rails should only see sub.example.org and not alt.example.org. So why is apache giving out https://alt.example.org^/login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but `https://alt.example.org/` (empty path) results in a `Location` header with the value `https://alt.example.org^/login`. Wow! What's causing that redirect with the `^` in the domain, and why does it reference alt instead of sub?

The `ProxyPassReverse` directive does not take a regex as the first argument and this would seem to be where the conflict is happening. And neither can this take `!` as the second argument. The `alt` subdomain would appear in the `Location` header if the `ProxyPassReverse` directive did not match the response.

You don't appear to need the first `ProxyPassReverse` directive that relates to `/login`, since this URL is not being proxied.

Also, these `ProxyPassMatch` directives appear to proxy everything to the root of `https://sub.example.org/` - do you not want to proxy to the corresponding URL-path at the target domain? Although, strangely, that does appear to be what's happening in your observed results? If you do want to proxy to the same URL-path then you can use the simpler `ProxyPass` directive instead and use simple prefix-matching as opposed to a regex.

> `alt.example.org/login` redirects to `sub.example.org/login`

Although that is not performed by the "redirect" you posted at the top, which would redirect to the document root, since the `$1` backreference is empty because there is no capturing subpattern in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. As you state later, "the Rails app itself is actually redirecting to `https://sub.example.org/login`".

So, in order to redirect to `sub.example.org/login` (which appears to be the intention) then you would need to change the directive to read something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/(login)$ https://sub.example.org/$1" [R,L]
```

The preceding `RewriteCond` directive is not required here, since that simply repeats the same check you are already performing in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

> ```
> RequestHeader set Host sub.example.org
> ```

This line is redundant, since this is the purpose of the preceding `ProxyPreserveHost off` directive.

> ```
> Header set Host alt.example.org
> ```

This line would also seem to be redundant, since `Host` is a request header, not a response header.

> ```
> ProxyPassMatch   ^/login ! # Prevent proxy on /login
> ```

Also, Apache does not support line-end comments. Only because of a "quirk" in the way Apache directives are processed prevents this particular line-end comment from breaking your server!

So, taking the above points into consideration, try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Externally Redirect "/login" to other domain
RewriteRule ^/(login)$ https://sub.example.org/$1" [R,L]

SSLProxyEngine on

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost off

# Prevent proxy on /login
ProxyPass /login !

# Proxy all other URLs
ProxyPass / https://sub.example.org/
ProxyPassReverse / https://sub.example.org/
```